# Is it possible to get a hashcode or any unique representation of a value?

Tags: hashcode, rascal

In Java, the `Object` class has a `hashCode()` function, which is useful to be able to get an (as much as possible) unique representation of an object. Does Rascal have something similar for `value`?

Purpose: I have a large `list[value]` (in which contents of a source code line are captures, eg `str`, `node`, `int`, etc.) and want to use it as a key in a lookup table (`map`).

Comment: Hashcodes in e.g. Java tell you when two things are definitely *unequal* but for equality, you should always perform further checks beyond just the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rascal you can use any value as a key in a map, if you only want certain fields to be important, I think the best way would be to create a new tuple with the fields that make up the key, and use that. But ik most cases, use the whole value, or perform a small simplification on the value.

Comment: Can a `list[value]` be a key? Doesn't that cause issues anywhere?

Comment: Any value can be a key. Just be careful around annotations (which are deprecated and you will only encounter on parse trees) since they don't count for equality

Comment: it will only cause issues if your lists are not "keys" in your data set, as in keys of an SQL data-store. Rascal uses structural equality to decide whether two values are the same or not and implements the JVM hashCode/equals contract to make it all work quickly and correctly.